# The call is ambiguous between x and x

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I've switched from Visual Studio to Visual Studio Code for development in Unity, ever since that I am getting over 1 thousand *"the call is ambiguous between some class member and some other class member*" everywhere, they are not real errors, I think something is wrong with my .SLN file in Unity but have no idea how to resolve it. Here is a photo of the issue:

[image: x]

I have tried deleting the SLN(keeping a copy of it before deletion) and making a new one, however, Unity doesn't seem to want to create a new one, so I have to resort to the copy I keep.

Has anyone else had this issue? And know how to resolve it?

Comment: do the errors actually show up in unity when it has finished importing your code? If not, its just vs code having stupid moments as it does.

Comment: @BugFinder nope, these don't show up in Unity, nor did they exist while developing in Visual Studio. It's quite an anomaly, they are definitely false. It appears every time a member in a class is used more than once, it throws a tantrum.

Comment: Try doing Assets/Open C# Project after deleting the sln

Comment: do you have the copy of the files in another directory in the project?

Comment: can we see an example on how you use or assign one of the variables/member?

Comment: @sertsedat there are no duplicates in the project directory, one variable that is getting this error is declared as public bool startTimer; in a class as usual, and every single instance of startTimer in the script is now getting the error, but not the actual member declaration itself

Comment: @zambari Should have thought about that before! That seemed to have worked, cheers

Comment: Are you using Unity Collaborate? I get these errors every time I sync to/from the server. Aiden's answer below will do the trick, as will closing and re-opening VSC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @zambari, **deleting the .SLN** and from unity going to assets -> **open C# project** resolved the issue.

This problem happens when **Unity makes changes outside of VS-Code**, and VS-Code is reading currently open classes, and the classes Unity saved into the SLN. Thereby **causing VS-Code to be reading duplicates**. *Reload VS-Code*! Ctrl+Shift+P -> Developer: Reload Window. If that does not work, follow the advice from the top...

Cheers everyone!