# Unity3D Error CS0229 - false ambiguity between variables

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with Unity (version 2020.3.5f1 LTS). In particular, I have moved a project from a computer to another, and I have this error several times:

> Error CS0229  Ambiguity between 'TimeCounter.singleton' and 'TimeCounter.singleton'

I know that this kind of error occurs when you have two different variables with the same name, as the compiler cannot distinguish between them; however, I do not have this particular situation. In fact, I have only one class `TimeCounter` in my project, and there are no repeated variables' names.

I have tried to fix this problem by deleting the .sln project and recreating it through Unity (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56216270/the-call-is-ambiguous-between-x-and-x)), however it did not work.

The class in which the error generates is the following one:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using EventSystem2;

public class TimeCounter : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float minutesToPlay = 2f;
    float currentTime = 0f;

    public GameEvent endedTimeEvent;

    private static TimeCounter singleton;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (!singleton)
        {
            singleton = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        currentTime = minutesToPlay * 60f;
    }

    IEnumerator Timer()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (currentTime > 0f)
            {
                currentTime -= 1f;
                print("current time: " + currentTime);
            }
            else 
            {
                endedTimeEvent.Raise();
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        }
    }

    public void StartTimer()
    {
        StartCoroutine(nameof(Timer));
    }
    
    public void StopTimer()
    {
        StopCoroutine(nameof(Timer));
    }

    public void ResetTimer()
    {
        currentTime = minutesToPlay * 60f;
    }

    public float GetTimeToPlayInMilliseconds() => (this.minutesToPlay * 60000);
    
    public float GetTimeToPlayInSeconds() => (this.minutesToPlay * 60);
}
```

This is the list of ambiguity errors I have:
[image]

Comment: this error show in unity? or only show in vistaul studio ?

Comment: This error shows also in Unity but with a different error code, error CS0111

Comment: error CS0111 for what ?

Comment: clean Library and temp ?

Comment: An example is `Type 'TimeCounter' already defines a member called 'Awake' with the same parameter types`. And this error repeats for every method of this class. It seems that the compiler (both in Unity and in VS) sees this class repeated twice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved! The `TimeCounter.cs` script was duplicated inside the Unity project (I do not know why it happened), therefore the compiled did not know to which version I was referring to.

Comment: tks veryyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy much