# Ambiguity between X and X

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, blazor

I have a Blazor project which I have synced to [Github](https://github.com/BuildItBusk/VirtualScoreCard). So when I got a new PC I just cloned the project and now I'm getting the following error everywhere:

> Ambiguity between 'NewRound.roundSettings' and
> 'NewRound.roundSettings' [GolfScoreUI]

Here it's `NewRound.roundSettings, but there is around 80 similar errors, all over the Blazor project (but not in any of the other projects. Here is how it looks in VS Code:

[image: Screenshot of the file explorer in VS Code]

The problem wasn't there on my old PC, when I pushed the code. Also the code runs just fine, so it seems to be "fake" errors.

I have seen similar issues, like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56216270/the-call-is-ambiguous-between-x-and-x), but the only solution suggestion I haven tried is to delete the solution file, since that doesn't really seem like a great solution.

Have anyone seen this problem before? And if so, how did you fix it?

**UPDATE 1:**

Some of the errors link me to a file that doesn't exist. But VS Code helps me create it. If I do this twice, I end up with two empty files, but the errors go away. What the duck?

[image: Empty files in VS Code]

**UPDATE 2:**

It works perfectly fine, when I open the solution in Visual Studio 2022. So it appears to be a problem with VS Code. If anyone manages to reproduce it, please let me know, so I can make an issue on the VS Code Github repo.

Comment: Close VS, delete the .vs folder. Open the Solution, do a Build|Clean, Build|Rebuild .

Comment: @HenkHolterman I don't have a `.vs` folder. Only `.vscode`. Deleting it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: OK, I missed that (vs-code) tag.

Comment: I just cloned the same repo and I do not get any errors

Comment: @DavidG are you also using VS Code - or a different IDE?

Comment: Try changing the version of the project to a later c# release

Comment: I did it in VS Code, Visual Studio 2022 and on command line with `dotnet build`

Comment: @ThomasAdrian I have tried changing the `<TargetFramework>` to net7.0. but the issue remains.
@DavidG I can also get `dotnet build` to work. It seems that there isn't any issue, but that VS Code is reporting it.

Comment: Isn't this just a intellisense error? We get these all the time in our winui projects. And ignore them, which seem te be no problem. Everything builds and works just fine.

Comment: @JHBonarius not sure what generates the warnings, but it definitely seems to be a UI issue, as the solution builds as intended. It's still a pretty big issue though, as it makes real errors harder to spot.

Comment: I've had the sort of similar error, but in my case it was due to same class defined under different namespace so it gave me  an ambigious error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Here is what fixed mine Extensions -> C# -> Omnisharp: Sdk Include Prereleases: False (unchecked). Or, put this in your settings.json

```
"omnisharp.sdkIncludePrereleases": false
```